# What is the noun for 'self-evident' or 'obvious'?

Tags: nouns

I am looking for a noun to describe something that is self-evident. I don't think I can say 'this is a self-evidency', but searching online and on this forum, I haven't found a proper alternative yet.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to provide a context, an example of how you want to use this noun.

Comment: The context in which I want to use it is this: 'The fact that all literature deals with it in such and such a way is a [self-evidency]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use the noun there?  Dropping the indefinite article and just using *self-evident* seems perfectly natural.

Answer (score 14):

*Given*, as in "The fact that .... is a given".

Answer (score 7):

I think *given* is the closest to what you described, but *presupposition* and *tautology* come to mind.

Answer (score 3):

*Obvious* can itself be a noun. You can speak of ‘stating the obvious’, for example. But it’s not a countable noun, so you can’t precede it with the indefinite article.

Comment: Would *patent* qualify? I wish it did, but as a noun, it has only a special meaning in law.

Comment: @Kris: You're right. I've just checked.

Comment: Yeah, I want to precede it with an indefinite article, that's the problem...

Comment: @Marieke: Then I think you'll be unlucky. The concept is by its nature non-countable.

Comment: It's the *obvious* answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wiktionary, [self-evidency](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-evidency) is such a noun.

Comment: Alas, Wiktionary says (and my ear agrees) that "self-evidency" is always uncountable and describes a _quality_, not an item.  That is, you can speak of "the self-evidency of" something, but speaking of something as "a self-evidency" would be an unusual usage at best.

Comment: I do not doubt that it is a valid construction, but it seems awkward to my American ears.

Answer (score 2):

In the example sentence you gave, if I absolutely had to use a noun, I'd probably go for a noun phrase like "self-evident fact", and preferably change the beginning to avoid the repetition of "fact":

> "That all literature deals with it in such and such a way is a self-evident fact."

But really, why can't you just say:

> "The fact that all literature deals with it in such and such a way is self-evident."

(I was originally going to suggest "[triviality](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triviality)", but it doesn't really fit the context you specified.  It *would* work in something like "We need not concern ourselves with such trivialities.")

Answer (score 2):

The word ***truism*** expresses the idea you are looking for, and can be used with an indefinite article.

> The fact that all literature deals with it in such and such a way is a *truism*.

Comment: I don't think this is quite the same.  I thought of "tautology", too, and rejected it for the same reason.  In each case, the meaning is "this is self-evident", whereas in the example, the desired meaning is "the large body of easily-available evidence makes this obvious".

Comment: Should the question be edited, then? A truism (dictionary.reference.com/browse/truism) is "a self-evident, obvious truth." That is, more than any other proposed word, an *exact* answer to the question, which asks for a synonym to "self-evidency" or a word that means "something that is self-evident."

Comment: See also http://www.wcdebate.com/1parli/29truism.htm which explains in detail the difference between a truism and a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to know the context but still you can check [axiomatic](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/axiomatic) and [axiom](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/axiom)

**Edit 1**: Possible to say

> The fact that all literature deals with it **in such and such a way** is the **proof** itself.

You could also use "obvious proof", "valid proof" e.t.c

Comment: The context in which I want to use it is this: 'The fact that all literature deals with it in such and such a way is a [self-evidency]

Comment: @Marieke, see my edit please.  (I, by mistake, edited your question)

Comment: By mistake, I edited  question instead of my answer, could moderators delete the edited part in OP's question?

Comment: +1 This would fit with the indefinite article: "… is an axiom".